# Links in android web-page get blue

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, pseudo-class

Links in android web page is getting blue when I'm pressing the element which have event listener or `a` tag. Maybe this is default behavior. How to override this behavior and customize? When using jQuery's `live` function it doesn't get blue and handles correctly. But I prefer CSS solution for this.`:active` css pseudo doesn't help. Here's my code:

```
a:active {
    background-color: white;
} 

<li style="text-align:right;">
    <a href="#categories"> <div>Categories</div> </a>
</li>
```

When I long press on "Categories" it'll get blue and gets back to normal on touchend.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `!important`:

```
a:active {
    background-color: white !important;
}
```